# Invariant ring using GAP

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, gap

How can I use GAP to find the polynomials of the invariant ring of a finite group?

I calculate the invariant ring of Dihedral groups but I want to use GAP to compare it with.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have already checked that the polynomials you got really are invariant.

Depending on how much theory you have seen, you could calculate the Molien Series to check whether dimensions agree.

Alternatively, you could implement the Reynolds operator as a sum over the group and calculate the image of the Reynolds operator to all monomials (up to a certain degree).

Comment: he is not asking how to find an invariant polynomial, but how to use GAP for doing so.